# Supabase module not found

Tags: swiftui, package, supabase, supabase-database, xcode15

I am trying to integrate supabase into my app but when i download the package and try to use it, it throws me an error that says:

No such module "supabase"

This is my package dependencies area where I downloaded the package:
[image]

This is my Supabase.swift file where I try and use it:

```
import Supabase

let supabase = SupabaseClient(
  supabaseURL: URL(string: "MyURL")!,
  supabaseKey: "MYKEY"
)
```

I have tried closing xcode and re-opening and redownloading the package multiple times. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue in my project. The problem might be that not all necessary packages are added. When adding the Supabase package, there are six packages in total that need to be included. However, in my case, the last one, the "Supabase" package, was not visible due to the window height and I accidentally missed it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/duJlb.png

I'd double check this and try adding that package if you haven't.